# Remover opções do campo input do tipo datetime-local

Tags: html, input, simpledateformat, datetime-local

Tenho um campo input do tipo datetime-local e preciso que ele fique o mais limpo possível, sem botões de limpeza ou passo e apenas exibindo a data e hora nesse formato: '12/12/2016 12:01', gostaria de saber como posso configurar esse campo.

Meu código:

```
<input id="prevSolucao" data-bind="value: prevSolucao, enable: !semPrevisao()" placeholder="Previsão de solução" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" style="padding-left: 13px;" autocomplete="off">
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de remover os botões laterais e que o calendário não fosse exibido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Com CSS - No Chrome

Você pode colocar todo o campo de digitação (`::-webkit-datetime-edit`), como 100%, o qual esconde o botão:

```css
input::-webkit-datetime-edit{
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local">
```

### Usando uma máscara

Use uma máscara. No seu caso, como não é necessário as funções desse campo, use um `input[text]` mesmo. No exemplo uso o [`Jquery Mask`](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

```js
$('#date-field').mask("00/00/0000 00:00", {placeholder: "__/__/____ 00:00"});
```

```css
input{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<label for="date-field">Datetime - local</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="date-field">
```

Comment: O problema nesse caso é que as datas não são validadas, por exemplo, posso entrar com a seguinte data '41/14/2016 25:98' inválida e o campo ira aceitar de boa.

Comment: @LeandroJ.S.Paiva, editado! Veja se lhe serve.

Comment: Era justamente isso que eu precisava, esta validando perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

## Ocultando diretamente o ícone do calendário com CSS

Você pode ocultar o ícone com CSS adicionado a propriedade `display:none;` a ele. Dessa forma:

```css
input[type="datetime-local"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="datetime-local"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" />
```

Essa forma de ocultá-lo garante que a estilização do input não precise de novas adaptações, como ocorreria se você usasse a solução de CSS da resposta anterior com o Vuetify 3.